# How to publish curves on geoserver?

Tags: geoserver, sql-server

On Sql Server i have a table:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[test](
[id] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
[geom] [geometry] NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_test] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
[id] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY] TEXTIMAGE_ON [PRIMARY]

GO
```

With data:

```
DECLARE @g geometry;
SET @g = geometry::STGeomFromText('
CURVEPOLYGON(
  CIRCULARSTRING(379821 1582021, 379816 1582026, 379821 1582031, 379826 1582026, 379821 1582021)
  )
 ',0);


INSERT INTO dbo.test(geom) select @g
```

But when i publish table on geoservet in Layer Preview u got error:

```
Unknown WKB type 10
```

Geoserver cannot work with Curves? Any advises?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

GeoServer supports curve geometries at the moment only with Oracle and PostGIS backends. See these blog posts:

http://www.geo-solutions.it/blog/getting-curvey-with-oracle-spatial-and-geoserver/

http://www.geo-solutions.it/blog/postgis-curves-in-geoserver/

Comment: Correct, the community is waiting for a code donation from someone that uses sql server, or funding to commercial support companies, in order to implement sql server curve support. See here for a guide on how to make it happen: https://github.com/geoserver/geoserver/wiki/Successfully-requesting-and-integrating-new-features-and-improvements-in-GeoServer

Comment: It's sad. But its fine. I will approximate geometry in database before publish it in geoserver.